# JQuery form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

What is the best JQuery way to ensure that all input fields with the attribute "required" are completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to check the value of each and then check the length property of the result:

```
var incomplete = $("input[required]").filter(function () {
    return this.value === "";
});
if (incomplete.length) {
    alert("Please fill in all the required fields");
}
```

Note that an attribute named `required` will invalidate your HTML.  `data-required` would be valid HTML5, however, or you could just give them all a class and use that as the selector (which would also be more efficient).

You could also use one of the validation plugins out there: http://google.com/search?q=jquery+validation.

Comment: Hi Andy thanks for this, you are right about HTML, but this is for HTML5 :)

Comment: @Russell: then you should use `data-required` for valid HTML5, without `data-` it's still invalid ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best JQuery validation plugin is:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

(At least the one I use and feel most comfortable with)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jquery validation plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference : 
[jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

For Example : [webreference](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jquery/form_validation/)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a plugin called 'valididty' that is worth a mention and is simpler to use IMO that the validation plugin.

http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try bValidator plugin (http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/) for form validation

Answer (score 0):

Just add two attributes at the end of your `input` tags:
`required="required" js-name="name_to_be_displayed"`

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">
$(function (){
    $("#submit").click(function (){
        $('input').each(function(index, value) {
            var attb = $(this).attr('required');
            var value = $(this).val();

            if (attb == "required" && value == "") {
                alert($(this).attr('js-name') + " " + 'value required');
                $(this).focus();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self">
<label> Name:   
<input name="Name:" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" required="required" js-name="Name" />
</label>
<br />
<label>Email:
<input name="Email:" type="email" value="" size="60" required="required" js-name="Email" />
</label>
<br />
<label>Phone:
<input name="Phone" type="text" size="60" required="required" js-name="Phone" /> 
</label>
<br />
<label>Country:
<input name="Country" type="text" size="60" required="required" js-name="Country" />
</label>
<br />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple jQuery plugin

http://suraj-mahajan.github.io/Validate-In-Grid-Controls/

Answer (score 0):

[valijate](http://valijate.com) plugin might help you. it uses 'data-xxxx' attributes for the validations. here is [form validation guide](http://valijate.com/Docs.php).